# Should We Be Using a GIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, mysql

I'm actually a graphic designer - the manufacturing company I work for wants to develop a map with layers for Regional Sales Managers territories, Internal Sales Associates territories, Local Rep territories - each with accompanying contact info. Our product is essentially specialized plumbing products, so we'd like a map layer displaying plumbing code territories, and another layer for Authorities Having Jurisdiction (the people responsible for determining plumbing codes, reviewing/planning projects). So there's going to be a several layers describing territories, likely a few layers with point locations, and a fair amount of related contact information, plumbing codes, etc. I'm also working on  setting up some interactive web pages which will feed information into a database for easy retrieval of select info for customers visiting our website and/or integration into the maps we develop. We're trying to figure out which mapping software and DBMS to use.

My supervisor started up a trial run using ArcGIS a few months ago, and I've been fooling around with MySQL for a database, which I have up and running (albeit a very simple test version). I've been looking at some other online mapping programs like Geometrx, eSpatial, build-a-map - not true GIS. I also fooled around with QGIS a bit, and while its definitely capable of everything we'd like to do, its seems like something geared more for a GIS expert - and doesn't have some of the basemaps readily accessible with ArcGIS like population density, vector based county and city boundary maps - I'm sure they exist, but I'd have to hunt them down/purchase them separately or create them from scratch.

So my real questions here are:

- Are we on the right track if we go with ArcGIS and a MySQL database?
- Is there a better mapping program to use for our particular needs?
- Are we better off keeping our database and maps separate, and manually updating one when the other changes?

Comment: MySQL probably isn't the greatest db to choose as far as spatial functionality goes.  MySQL doesn't interface with ArcGIS, but Postgres does.  PostGIS is the spatial extention for postgres.  Check out OpenGeo Suite for all the software tools you would need in a single open source package. http://opengeo.org/products/suite/register/

Comment: Can you give a sample interaction with your customer and the map?

Comment: Sure, the customer would visit our website, and go to the map page - enter their address/zoom in on a location (lets say Gotham City). Clicking on the locale would tell them that Robin is our company's sales guy, Batgirl is our company's customer service gal, the local distributor of our product is Jack Napier of Joker Plumbing Products, the region uses the 2010 International Plumbing Code, and the plumbing code authority is Gotham Public Utilities (The Penguin handles plan review, the Riddler does sizing, Two-Face does construction inspections, and Catwoman does maintenance inspections).

Comment: Internally, we'd be able to see all this info plus population density (to ensure our territories are evenly divided among our sales and customer service peeps), internal sales stuff that customers don't need to see. I could also see the customer facing map being two or three separate maps, unless we have a way for customers to be able to turn various layers on or off on their own.

Comment: We do have a page for literature requests which currently generates a form that is emailed to our generic inbox. I'd like to see that info captured into a database to we can easily see where our hot spots are and focus sales efforts in those regions. Not only will the database coordinate with our maps, I have to be able to develop php script that can connect to it as well for website applications that don't necessarily have anything to do with the map.

Answer (score 7):

Based on your descriptions, you don't need a GIS as much as you need the data. You said it yourself: You'd have to track down administrative border data and census data. (If you let us know which area of the world you need, we might be able to offer guidance.)

The GIS functionality mentioned so far is limited to simple "Identify" operations in a web map. I don't think it is worth to pay license fees if you are not planning to use more functionality than display and identify. My experience is that commercial web mapping solutions are preferred in settings with existing commercial GIS infrastructure since there is hope to use existing knowledge and support connections. This does not seem to be the case at your work place.

What I would do:

1. Work on collecting all requirements for the application.
2. Track down necessary data for your area of the world.
3. Prepare the data by merging population data with data specific to your use case. (You can use e.g. QGIS for this step.)
4. Publish on the web.

Before your last comment, I would have recommended to look into simple solutions down to Google Fusion Tables or QGIS Cloud for publishing.

But since you added in your comment that you want the extend the application with some PHP (to log user accesses?) you might be better off developing your website using OpenLayers or Leaflet.

Answer (score 0):

PostGIS + Geoserver + Openlayers/php/whateverinterface for web and QGIS + PostGIs for data generation / modifying or some web interface. Simple